# Webcam doesn't display when node.js it's running

Tags: javascript, node.js, webcam

I have a script that takes a picture from my webcam.
it's working fine when i runs locally or when i see in a online server.

But when i run the html file from the node.js, it doesnt show the view from my webcam.

how to fix that?

MY SERVER IN NODE:

```
// app.js

var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
sys = require('util');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', function(err, html){
    console.log("oi");
    response.writeHeader(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.write(html);
    response.end();
  });
});

server.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Executando Servidor HTTP');
});
```

MY HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Webcam Demo - <MyCodingTricks/></title>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Demonstrates simple 320x240 capture &amp; display</h3>


<div id="my_camera"></div>

    <!-- A button for taking snaps -->

<form>
        <input type=button class="btn btn-success" value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">
    </form>


<div id="results" class="well">Your captured image will appear here...</div>

    <!-- First, include the Webcam.js JavaScript Library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="2/webcam.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Configure a few settings and attach camera -->
    <script language="JavaScript">
        Webcam.set({
            width: 320,
            height: 240,
            image_format: 'jpeg',
            jpeg_quality: 90
        });
        Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
        function take_snapshot() {
            // take snapshot and get image data
            Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
                // display results in page
                document.getElementById('results').innerHTML =
                    '<h2>Here is your image:</h2>' +
                    '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/>';

                                Webcam.upload( data_uri, 'upload.php', function(code, text) {
                                            // Upload complete!
                                            // 'code' will be the HTTP response code from the server, e.g. 200
                                            // 'text' will be the raw response content
                                });
            } );
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: From the look of it, your server does not serve `2/webcam.min.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program seems to be sending the content of `index.html` for **every** request (for html, icons, scripts, etc.). Maybe try using [`express`](http://expressjs.com/) to serve static files properly:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Executando Servidor HTTP');
});
```

It's even easier than the way you want to write it, because to make your script work you would have to manually route the requests based on the `request` object to properly send scripts and different assets, make sure to handle MIME types, paths like `../..` etc.

Also you may want to move your static files (html, css, js) to a different directory like `static` and change the `app.js` like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Executando Servidor HTTP');
});
```

so that no one will be able to get your `app.js` code by browsing to: http://localhost:3000/app.js